# Understanding window.onerror

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following code:

```
window.onerror = function (message, url, line, column, error) { ... }
```

The message and error seems to be identical when printed? What's the difference with these two?

Comment: error is an object, if you print it its .toString() is called & returns the message property string automatically.

Comment: is message same as error.toString()?

Comment: error.toString() returns the internal value of message, see http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.11.4.4 - note its not guaranteed to be the case if there is a `name`.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onerror

From site:

- Error message (string)
- URL of the script where the error was raised (string)
- Line number where error was raised (number)
- Column number for the line where the error occurred (number)
- Error Object (object)

Error object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error